# Como mostrar resultados con diferentes id de una misma consulta?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

tengo el siguiente codigo el cual deseo mostrar todas las personas de un mismo dia, he logrado mostrarlo pero me muestra solo el mismo id.
que puedo estar haciendo mal?

```
 $mm=date('M');
    $dd=date('d');
    $strConsulta = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE mes='$mm' AND dia='$dd' ";//error_reporting(0);
    $result = $conexion->query($strConsulta);
    while( $row = $result->fetch_array() )
    {
 //aqui valores

}
```

Comment: ¿Cuántas veces te muestra el mismo id? ¿podrías mostrarnos un ejemplo de datos almacenados?

Comment: La estructura de la tabla user tambien vendria bien...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta asi:

```
$strConsulta = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE mes='".$mm."' AND dia='".$dd."' ";
```

Si quieres mostrar todos has un foreach de esta manera:

```
foreach ($strConsulta as $row) {
  echo $row->id;
}
```